# cakephp3 unable to insert data in associated tables using 'associated' method

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I am using one table:UserMasters and associate with PersonMasters using:

```
 $this->hasOne('person_masters', [
            'className' => 'person_masters',
            'foreign_key'=>'user_master_id',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
```

But when i am saving data it only save data in user_masters table.i am also using 'associated' method in patchEntity. but it not worked..Here is my code for save data:

```
$user = $this->UserMasters->newEntity(); 
       $user = $this->UserMasters->patchEntity($user,   $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['person_masters']]);
```

It only save data to user_masters ..so how can i also save data in person_masters in cakephp3?? 
thanks in advance...

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `person_masters` isn't accessible, it won't be assigned like this.

> The _accessible property allows you to provide a map of properties and whether or not they can be mass-assigned. The values true and false indicate whether a field can or cannot be mass-assigned.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment

also use table alias for defining associations.

```
$this->hasOne('PersonMasters', [
        'className' => 'PersonMasters',
        'foreign_key'=>'user_master_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ]);
```

Comment: i already assign ' * '= true in PersonMaster.php in Entity..here is my code:class PersonMaster extends Entity {
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true
    ]; Still unable to save data in person_masters table..

Comment: You need to make it accessible in `UserMasters`. Also see my answer.

Comment: i already assign ' * '=true in every entity, including UserMasters...still not works..

Comment: got my ans ..i was wrong in .ctp file ...from (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs) got my ans ..thanks for suggestions..