# Cakephp 3.0 Save hasOne associated model

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

using one table:UserMasters and associate it with PersonMasters using:

```
    $this->hasOne('person_masters', [
                'className' => 'person_masters',
                'foreign_key'=>'user_master_id',
                'dependent' => true
            ]);
```

But when i am saving data it only save data in user_masters table.i am also using 'associated' method in patchEntity. but it not worked..Here is my code for save data:

```
    $user = $this->UserMasters->newEntity(); 
           $user = $this->UserMasters->patchEntity($user,   $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['person_masters']]);
```

It only save data to user_masters.i already assign ' * '= true in PersonMaster.php in Entity..here is my code:

`class PersonMaster extends Entity { protected $_accessible = [ '*' => true ];`

In .ctp file:
$this->Form->input('person_master.email');
It only save email field in person_master table..and while i only use
 $this->Form->input('email');
it only save data in user_masters..

so how can i save same field email to both person_masters and user_masters?? thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cakephp3 unable to insert data in associated tables using 'associated' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038457/cakephp3-unable-to-insert-data-in-associated-tables-using-associated-method)

Comment: my question is that if i want to save 'Email' fields to both user_masters as well as person_masters then what should i do??Is there any changes in .ctp file or controller??

Comment: Repeating the question in a comment is not helpful. Sounds like you just need to put the email value in two places in the data array - I don't understand how that's confusing.